# Find a string and display the line number and the line itself?

Tags: java, file, recursion

I'm designing a program that reads the size of a txt file, the number of words, numbers, and characters it contains, and the ability to search the file for a given string.

For example.

A txt file has

> There once was a land
>
> That land no longer exists.
>
> That land was...

If I wanted to search "land" it would list all 3 lines.

The methods I created to search the file and find the string are:

```
public String searchWord(String key) throws Exception {

    LineNumberReader lnr = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(f));
    String line = null;
    line = recursiveSearch(lnr.readLine(), key, lnr);

    return line;
}

public String recursiveSearch(String currentLineText, String key, LineNumberReader lnr)
        throws Exception {

    if (currentLineText != null) {
        String lCase = currentLineText.toLowerCase();
        if (lCase.contains(key.toLowerCase())) {

            return ("Line " + lnr.getLineNumber() + ": " + currentLineText
                    + "\n");
        }
    }
    return recursiveSearch(lnr.readLine(), key, lnr);
}
```

The program does indeed search through the files properly, so I have to assumed searchWord is working properly. However, if I were to type "land" it would only return "There once was a land" rather than all 3 lines.

If I were to type "longer" it would return the second line properly. What directions can you give me to show all required lines?

EDIT

I've went with MadProgrammer's advice, and I believe he is right. A list will be needed. However, after I re-did the code

```
  public List<String> searchWord(String key) throws Exception {

    LineNumberReader lnr = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(f));

    return recursiveSearch(lnr.readLine(), key, lnr);
 }


 public List<String> recursiveSearch(String currentLineText, String key, LineNumberReader lnr)
        throws Exception {
     List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<String>();
   
    if (currentLineText != null) {
        String lCase = currentLineText.toLowerCase();
        if (lCase.contains(key.toLowerCase())) {

            String result = ("Line " + lnr.getLineNumber() + ": " + currentLineText
                    + "\n");
            resultList.add(result);
        }
    }
    String nextLine = lnr.readLine();
    if (nextLine != null) {
        resultList.addAll(recursiveSearch(nextLine, key, lnr));
    }
    return resultList;
}
```

The test class came with an error. The program did not find "searchMethod"

```
  f.selectFile();

  if (f.exists()) {
     try {
         String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a word ");
         for (String line : searchWord(input)) {
              display(line);
         }
```

I probably need to rewrite a portion of the test class, or look for more example of Lists to get a better understanding.

EDIT 2

So I just sent the two methods in my test Class and Renamed them with "Static"
Everything is working. I prefer not to do that, but now I just gotta have the FileReader choose the file by user inputs, should be easy for me. Thanks guys.

Comment: The `return ("Line " + lnr.getLineNumber() + ": " + currentLineText + "\n");` will short circuit your recursive search.  Try adding the results to a `List` and return the `List` at the end of the method, making sure that you use something like `list.addAll(recursiveSearch(lnr.readLine(), key, lnr));` to pick the other results ;)

Comment: load file into a temporary db tables and use SQL to search.  Then you can re-use the data for other searches.

Comment: @ScaryWombat Really no SQL needed here.

Comment: @user1803551 I did not say it was `needed` - just a suggestion.  If the text file is very long, then using SQL will be a lot optimal than any home-brewed solution. OK?

Comment: @ScaryWombat Even so, using SQL would be a home-brewed solution to some extent--I saw this title, and immediately thought of using grep. :P

Comment: @anorton Yep, grep would be optimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your search routines are guard to only find a single word...

```
return ("Line " + lnr.getLineNumber() + ": " + currentLineText + "\n");
```

Will stop any further execution and return to the caller, never looking for any new results.  The fact that you only return a `String` is another problem, as you can never find more than a single `String`, unless you intend to concatenate the results

A better solution would be to allow the method to return an array or `List` of results, adding each result to the `List` as it's found and then adding all the results found from the subsequent calss to `recursiveSearch`, for example...

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.LineNumberReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            for (String line : searchWord("land")) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (Exception exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static List<String> searchWord(String key) throws Exception {

        LineNumberReader lnr = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(new File("StuffToRead.txt")));

        return recursiveSearch(lnr.readLine(), key, lnr);
    }

    public static List<String> recursiveSearch(String currentLineText, String key, LineNumberReader lnr)
                    throws Exception {

        List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>(25);
        if (currentLineText != null) {
            String lCase = currentLineText.toLowerCase();
            if (lCase.contains(key.toLowerCase())) {

                results.add("Line " + lnr.getLineNumber() + ": " + currentLineText);
            }
            results.addAll(recursiveSearch(lnr.readLine(), key, lnr));
        }
        return results;
    }

}
```

Comment: I can not really see the use of using a recursive function. a while loop would be fine.

Comment: @ScaryWombat Me neither, but I assume the OP is doing some recursive method self teaching or some such ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a single line from recursiveSearch() method. You should be returning a list of lines. Then your this problem will be solved.

Something like ...

```
public List<String> recursiveSearch(String currentLineText, String key, LineNumberReader lnr)
        throws Exception {
    List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (currentLineText != null) {
        String lCase = currentLineText.toLowerCase();
        if (lCase.contains(key.toLowerCase())) {

            String result = "Line " + lnr.getLineNumber() + ": " + currentLineText + "\n";
            resultList.add(result);
        }
    }
    String nextLine = lnr.readLine(); 
    if(nextLine != null) {
         resultList.addALL(recursiveSearch(nextLine, key, lnr));
    }
    return resultList;
}
```